# Building Svelte app with Rollup - css bundle different every build

Tags: svelte, rollup

We are building a Svelte app and using Rollup to compile the components into the JS, the JS Map, and the CSS. When we run the build, even if we've changed nothing in the source code, the compiled CSS is different every time.

This causes headaches when we're doing code reviews, etc - because the compiled CSS appears to change even when there is not change in underlying s inside the components. (At this point we must commit the compiled CSS due to technological reasons.)

Is there a way to make the build process more predictable, more deterministic?

- We've tried using cssHash
- We've tried disabling tree-shaking

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/project/project_browser/issues/3281173

Comment: What are the changes in the css? What went wrong with your other attempts?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the styles are pulled from files in a random order, due to async nature of file loading or something maybe. We can force them all to compile in the same order using something like this in our rollup config:

```js
    css({ output:(styles, styleNodes) => {
      let orderedStyles = '';
      // To ensure the CSS files are compiled in the same order on every build,
      // sort alphabetically by the CSS file's path.
      Object.keys(styleNodes)
        .sort()
        .forEach((fromFile) =>  {
          orderedStyles += styleNodes[fromFile];
        });
      writeFileSync('./public/build/bundle.css', orderedStyles);
    }, }),
```